# How to check any response value matches its property value

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a piece of code below that checks that every value of `regionId` (found under `region.hotels.regionId`) matches its property value `regionid_request`.

```
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

def regionid_request = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("regionid") as Integer

        region.hotels.each { hotel ->
            assert hotel.regionId == regionid_request

        }
```

I want the code above to perform slightly differently. Instead of saying each regionid needs to match its property value, I just want any of regionid to match its property value. In other words I want to ensure when I have my response, that at least one of the regionIds matches the property value.

What needs to be changed above to match this condition?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just

```
assert region.hotels.regionId.contains(regionid_request)
```